# inputting foreign key value of a column during bulk copy or insert?

Tags: sql, csv

Oddball question, but I'd like to insert a csv into my database. one of the columns in the table references a foreign key. i was wondering if it were possible to change the value of the the column upon insert to reflect the value of the foreign key.

sorry it sounds convoluted, but here's an example...

```
table: players                                  table: country
playerid | playerName | countryID ------------- countryID | countryName
```

I'd like to insert into the players table, but rather than `countryID`... the csv I have has country names instead. Is it possible to change something like this...

```
george, england
```

to

```
george, 1
```

upon insert?

thank you and sorry for the goofy question/phrase

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are doing a bulk insert but it still seams to me you should handle that before you do the insert in the database.

You don't say what is the database you are using and how you are calling that. Without knowing that I would suggest a trigger before insert to do that before the insert, but it really doesn't sound the answer in terms of performance.

My solution would be to read line by line (a db function for example) handle the country first and insert the player after with the result from that.

Comment: thank you for the reply. i was thinking something along the lines of what you were saying...make sure the country table was set, then handle the player table, but i was wondering if, during the insert of the players, there was some sort of:

insert countryID where @countryName = countryName

kind of function during insert. i've been googling like a madman but can't seem to find anything, at least anything that makes sense to a dql newbie ;)